# PDFLib opinions/experiences

Tags: java, api, pdf, dynamic, pdflib

My organization is considering PDFlib for dynamically creating PDF files (http://www.pdflib.com/) in our Java (Spring/Tomcat) environment.

Does anyone have experiences that they can share about the pro/cons of this Library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've been using PDFlib for a few years but we switched to [DynaPDF](http://www.dynaforms.com/index.htm) recently (we are not using Java but C++). There never were any issues with the PDFlib - it always worked stable and reliable (and we really used all features including spot colors and importing of other PDFs).

It contains very good documentation and their support is fine, too.

Unfortunately, depending on what features of PDFlib you need, it is *very* expensive. We requested a 3-platform license without royalties (the PDI-enabled version), and were offered a licence for around 20,000 €. This is a bit expensive for a small company like ours.

So eventually we moved on to [DynaPDF](http://www.dynaforms.com/index.htm), which is less expensive and creates PDF files just as reliable. We got a license including source code for about €1000. I'm not sure if they provide Java wrappers, though.

Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842172/pdflib-java-api) might be interesting for you.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Iv been using pdfLib for about 3 years now and its been great for me. i guess it really depends on what you want to use it for but for me its been really good. I do a lot of file maniuplations and so far its been able to do everything i need very well. Support can be better but overall its not too bad but the software itself is great.